# Mapper writing to HDFS and Reducer writing to HBase table

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have a map reduce job (say Job1) in which the mapper extends

> Mapper < Object, Object, KeySet, ValueSet >

Lets say I want to do summation of all values in ValueSet in the reduction step.

***After reducing (key, Iterable), I want to write the final reduced values to HBase table instead of HDFS, in reducer of Job1*** The table in HBase will be used for future jobs.

I know I can write a mapper only Job2 which reads the reduced file in HDFS (written by Job1)  and import the data to HBase table, but I want to avoid two redundant I/O operations.

I don't want to change the Mapper class of Job1 to write to HBase because there are only specific values that I want to write to the HBase table, others I want to continue writing to HDFS.

Has anyone tried something similar and can provide pointers? 
I've looked at [HBase mapreduce: write into HBase in Reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603031/hbase-mapreduce-write-into-hbase-in-reducer) but my question is different since I don't want to write anything to HBase in mapper.

Comment: What's the problem in adding the values in reducer and writing the result in HBase from reducer itself?I'm sorry, but I didn't quite get the question.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. If I use HBase client API in reducer itself, it really slows down the whole thing, I guess to do with the HTable instantiation in the reduce every time. I want to know if there is a way that the table instance could be passed on to reduce()?